# Page doesn't always recognize ng-if/new $scope variables with ES6 promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angular-promise, es6-promise

Weird issue -

So, I run code that loads a user's profile. During the code it does a check to see if the person viewing the profile is a 'friend'. If they are, it uses NG-IF and also sets a $scope.button to have new text.

However - often times I need to refresh the page several times for Angular/http-server to see this. I can see the connection is correct in console.log but the problem persists. If I don't need to refresh, I see "flickering" and watch the scope change as the page loads.

Is there a way to prevent this?

I have tried $scope.apply();.
(pulling data from firebase)

Comment: Use [$q.when](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when) to convert ES6 promises to $q promises that are integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle.

Comment: thanks. works perfectly. i was using Promises.all and $q seems to have fixed this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the promise comes from outside the AngularJS framework, the framework is unaware of changes to the model and does not update the DOM. Use `$q.when` to convert the external promise to an Angular framework promise.

```
var ref = x.child(userLoggedIn).child(allUsersArray[i].uid)
var refPromise = $q.when(ref.once('value'));
```

Use $q Service promises that are properly integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle.

> ### $q.when
>
> Wraps an object that might be a value or a (3rd party) then-able promise into a `$q` promise. This is useful when you are dealing with an object that might or might not be a promise, or if the promise comes from a source that can't be trusted.
>
> [-- AngularJS $q Service API Reference - $q.when](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when)

---

*i was using Promises.all and $q seems to have fixed this behavior.*

Under the hood, `$q.all` uses `$q.when` for each of the promises in the object or array. This will also convert the external promises to an Angular framework promise.